# Title: Full Stack Web Development Assignment-Shadow and Z-Lock for Cube using React.js and Three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-drei

Title: Full Stack Web Development Assignment-Shadow and Z-Lock for Cube using React.js and Three.js

Objective:

The objective of this assignment is to check the technical skills in building a web application using the full stack (SQLite, C#, React.js, three.js) and integrating Three.js for 3D graphics. The specific focus will be on creating a cube with realistic shadows and implementing a Z-Lock feature (Its means cube can be rotated in left and right its cant rotates top and bottom). Also perform CRUD operation for creating case, delete case, edit case data.

Requirements:

1. Setup C# Project:

Set up a new C# project with SQLite as the database, C# as the backend framework, React.js for the frontend.

2. Cube Implementation with Three.js:

Create a simple 3D cube using Three.js.

Implement basic controls to rotate, pan, and zoom the cube using Three.js controls.

3. Shadow Generation:

Implement realistic shadows for the cube using Three.js.

Experiment with different shadow types and configurations to achieve a visually appealing result.

4. Z-Lock Feature:

Implement a Z-Lock feature for the cube using React.js.

The Z-Lock feature should allow users to lock the cube in the Z-axis, preventing rotation along that axis while still allowing rotation in other directions.

5.. Integration with SQLite DB:

Set up SQLite DB and create a schema for storing cube-related data. (Case width length, height)

Implement CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations for cube data in the SQLite database.

6. User Interface:

Create a user-friendly interface for the web application using React.js.

Include controls and options for interacting with the 3D cube, toggling the Z-Lock feature, and viewing cube-related data.

7. Submission Guidelines:

Create a GitHub repository for the project and submit the link along with any additional instructions.

Include a README file that provides an overview of the project, instructions for setting it up, and any other relevant information.

guys please help me in this assignment.

Comment: Please see [help] section on asking about homework questions

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what kind of help you need. Nobody's going to do your entire assignment for you.